# Add second caption to polar coordinates based ggplot2 plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been asked to recreate a pie chart using `ggplot2` and am having difficulty adding a second caption to the plot. I need a caption on the bottom left of the plot *and* the bottom right.

My current approach can get one or the other by using the `hjust` option for the caption placement (0 for left-align; 1 for right-align):

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(variable = c("V1", "V2", "V3"),
                  value = c(.80,.50,.63))
p1 <- ggplot(dat, 
             aes(x = 1, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar(theta = "y")  +
  theme(legend.position = 'none',
        plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 1)) +
  labs(caption  = "RIGHT CAPTION")

print(p1)
```

This produces:

[image: Pie chart with right caption]

I've seen some approaches that use `annotate()` but I cannot seem to get them to work with `coord_polar()`.

Does anyone know how I can get a second caption to appear on the left-hand side of the plot (horizontally aligned with the right caption)? Maybe it is possible to overlay a blank layer that only has a left caption?

Comment: I am definitely not above using hacky solutions but I'm hoping there is a way to do this that is a bit more reproducible. This solution would require a lot of trial and error with the number of spaces to include between the left and right captions and depending on how the plot is saved/exported, that value might change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `grid` package it is possible to add a text grob containing the left caption.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
dat <- data.frame(variable=c("V1", "V2", "V3"), value=c(.80,.50,.63))

p1 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = 1, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  theme(legend.position='none', plot.caption=element_text(hjust=1)) +
  labs(caption="RIGHT CAPTION")

# Generate a ggplot2 plot grob
p2 <- ggplotGrob(p1)
# Find the grob tree containing the right caption (as child)
k <- which(p2$layout$name=="caption")
# Copy the "right caption" text grob in grbTxt
grbTxt <- p2$grobs[[k]]$children[[1]]

# Modify content and position of the text grob  
grbTxt$label <- "LEFT CAPTION"
grbTxt$name <- "GRID.text.left"
grbTxt$x <- unit(0,"npc")
grbTxt$hjust <- 0
grbTxt$gp$col <- "red"

# Add grbTxt (left caption) to the title grob containing the right caption
p2$grobs[[k]] <- addGrob(p2$grobs[[k]],grbTxt)
grid.draw(p2)
```

[image]

Comment: Very cool! Just to understand this a bit better: in this case `addGrobs()` adds a new child to the caption list? Looking this over quickly, I would have originally assumed that it would overwrite the stuff located in `p2$grobs[[k]]`.

Comment: @Twitch_City Yes, `addGrobs` adds a new child to the caption grob (a `gTree`). We cannot overwrite `p2$grobs[[k]]`, otherwise we loose the right (child) caption.